# fixtures for error during execution of trigger .EMPLOYEE_AUDIT_TRIGGER, integrity constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to run this trigger which is suppose to log a transaction each time the Employee table is modified.

Heres the trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMPLOYEE_AUDIT_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON EMPLOYEE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS (TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP, USERNAME, EMP_ID, POSITION_TYPE)
  VALUES (SYSTIMESTAMP, GET_USERNAME(), :NEW.EMP_ID, 'HR');
END;
```

The get_username function is just an ordinary function that i defined that returns the username of the current user. Without the trigger, I can enter the employee into the Employee table without any errors, so its definetly not an error with that just something wrong with the trigger

The trigger was suppose to log a transaction

However, I keep running into this error:

```
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (xxxx.SYS_xxxxx) violated - parent key
not found
ORA-06512: at "xxxxx.EMPLOYEE_AUDIT_TRIGGER", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'xxxxx.EMPLOYEE_AUDIT_TRIGGER'
```

Comment: The TRANSACTIONS seems to have a foreign key. But a delete trigger has no new values.

Comment: You should check out the foreign key constraint within the transactions table along with the values in the parent table related to that constraint.

Comment: (TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP(6), USERNAME VARCHAR2(20) REFERENCES LOGIN(USERNAME), EMP_ID NUMBER(3) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMP_ID), 
POSITION_TYPE VARCHAR2(10) REFERENCES POSITIONS(POSITION_TYPE),
CONSTRAINT T_PRIMARY PRIMARY KEY (TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP, USERNAME, EMP_ID)); there doesnt seem to be a problem with the transactions table

Comment: Just select * from all_constraints where constraint_name='xxxx.SYS_xxxxx' (the actual cosntraint name in the error message! BTW: it's not good to have PK and FK constraint names be given by the system. They should be given relevant names on creation). Then look into all_conss_columns and in the r_constraint_name to see what that columns should refer what in which table.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle says that you are trying to insert a value which doesn't exist in parent table.

That *parent* table is referenced from `transactions` table via foreign key constraint.

- `transaction_timestamp` is OK
- `username`: why don't you use built-in `user` function?
- `emp_id`: seems to be OK; pseudorecord suggests so. Beware of *old* and *new* values (new don't exist when you're deleting rows, so perhaps you'd want to use `coalesce(:new.emp_id, :old.emp_id)`)
- `position_type`: what is `HR`? Is there a foreign key on that column? Does it exist in parent table?

Comment: I can not use the build-in user function as it is for Get_Username() returns a local username value referring to the login table. The system user remains the same. <br/>Will change to coalesce(:new.emp_id, :old.emp_id) <br/>HR is a sample input, the transactions table requires the position of the employee that's being modified. I haven't about that much so for now I'm just leaving that as any value.

Comment: OK. I'd, though, say that this is not the culprit anyway.

Comment: is there a better way to go about it, would love to implement a way that I can refer to a local login and get a username. Instead of this long and weird process. CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_USERNAME RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  USERNAME VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  SELECT USERNAME INTO USERNAME
  FROM LOGIN
  WHERE SESHINFO = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USERID')
    AND ROWNUM = 1;

  RETURN USERNAME;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;

Comment: I guess not; if users were distinguished within the database, you could have used USER function (as I said), but - as you said you can't do it - use your own function. There's nothing wrong about it.

Answer (score 0):

You have the `transactions` table with the DDL that includes:

```sql
EMP_ID NUMBER(3) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(EMP_ID)
```

and your trigger is:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMPLOYEE_AUDIT_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON EMPLOYEE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS (TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP, USERNAME, EMP_ID, POSITION_TYPE)
  VALUES (SYSTIMESTAMP, GET_USERNAME(), :NEW.EMP_ID, 'HR');
END;
```

There are three problems:

1. It is a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger so you are trying to insert the `EMP_ID` into the `transactions` table before it exists in the `employee` table and there is going to be no row for the referential constraint to reference (yet). You could fix this by changing the trigger to `AFTER INSERT` or deferring the evaluation of the constraint but that won't fix the next issue.
2. It will trigger on `DELETE` and, in that case, the row with the `EMP_ID` is about to be removed from the `employee` table, which will fail because there is a referential constraint in the `transactions` table that requires the parent key to exist.
3. `:NEW.EMP_ID` will be `NULL` when you are deleting a row from the `employee` table.

To fix it you need to:

- Drop the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint on `transactions.emp_id` because you still want the transactions to exist when you have deleted the employee and the constraint is not necessary (and is what is causing the errors).
- Change `:NEW.EMP_ID` to `COALESCE(:NEW.EMP_ID, :OLD.EMP_ID)` in the trigger's `INSERT`.

*Note: If rows can be deleted from the `LOGIN` and `POSITIONS` tables then you may want to remove all the foreign keys from the `transactions` tables as you would then have similar issues with those columns.*